# Cloud Firestore ReactJS Error: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm fairly new to Cloud Firestore particularly security roles, but being that they're significantly important I'd rather start the new build of the project surrounding them.

Now as a basic insight, I have a dashboard of which users have to sign in with their email addresses and passwords, of which then they can access data such as regional information. To start off with the security rules, I figured I'd start out simple, and yet as the title states I'm getting:

`Error: Missing or insufficient permissions`

I've looked at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /regions/{region} {
        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
        }

        function getRole(rsc) {
          // Read from the "roles" map in the resource (rsc).
          return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid];
        }

        function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
          // Determine if the user is one of an array of roles
          return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);
        }

                // Any role can read regions.
        allow read: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter', 'reader']);
        }
  }
}
```

I have a collection of regions and each region has a title, along with a roles map having for example:

```
roles: {
(uid): "owner",
(uid2): "writer",
(uid3): "reader",
}
```

Thanks for your help, I feel like I'm missing something real simple. The check for `isSignedIn()` works, but the check of roles does not.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the minimal code that reads from the database and raises this error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for my misunderstanding but what minimal code are you referring to? The console log is a single line error. The code is a simple `db.collection("project").get().....`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal complete code that reproduces the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (check out the link, it's quite useful). Note that immediately I spot that your code refers to `project`, while your security rules don't have any match for that collection (and this don't allow access to it).

Comment: Thanks, and whoops ... `db.collection("regions").get()....`

Comment: What does isSignedIn returns? Could you log it? And Could you call isSignedIn and getRole one per line in isOneOfRoles?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you make the database query?