# PERMISSION DENIED Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use to use the texts from firebase app, each Page View for each text, but it's giving me this log of permissions denied, i've also tried using FutureBuilder but it was giving the same error.

**My error log :**

> W/Firestore(28023): (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(teste)
>   failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or
>   insufficient permissions., cause=null}
>       I/System.out(28023): com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>       W/Firestore(28023): (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(lessons) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED,
>   description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
>       I/System.out(28023): com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

**The code:**

```
    class LessonPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final LessonData lessonData;

  LessonPage(this.lessonData);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("lessons").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              "An Has Error Occurred",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24.0),
            ),
          );
        }
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case ConnectionState.none:
            {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Without Connection!",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24.0),
                ),
              );
            }
          case ConnectionState.done:
          case ConnectionState.active:

          default:
          return PageView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return LessonWidget(
                  LessonData.fromDocument(snapshot.data.documents[index]));
            },
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**LessonWidget class(i'm getting the lesson text document snapshot from firebase, and putting in my Text):**

```
    class LessonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final LessonData lessonData;

  LessonWidget(this.lessonData);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("${lessonData.text == null ? lessonData.text : "" }", style:
        TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 30.0),),
        SizedBox(height: 18.0,),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Escreva a sua resposta aqui"
          ),
          autofocus: true,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: () {

        },
          color: Theme
              .of(context)
              .primaryColor,
          child: Text("Continuar"),)
      ],
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably your database rules. Did you check the rules in firebase console? take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions) too.

Comment: i've already resolved it, but now i'm with another problem: "the getter text was called on null". Im using the code Text("${lessonData.text == null ? lessonData.text : "" }"),

Comment: "the getter text was called on null" is because your lessonData instance is null. A good approach to avoid null is using dart null-aware operators. You can try Text( ${lessonData?.text ?? "Null lessonData text" }" ); Take a look [here](http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html) for dart null-aware operators. I hope it helps.

Comment: I've changed the text conditions and  put it the PageView.builder inside a FutureBuilder

Comment: It's working?By the way i see brazilian portuguese in your source...

Comment: yes it is, and the app language is going to be pt BR

Comment: Good,  your app will be open source? If yes maybe I can help with some codes. I am from Brazil.

Comment: maybe it will be, i'm making for someone, but thanks :D

Comment: @LíviaCastilholiSantiago Are you able to resolve this problem? If yes, then how?

Comment: IMO you should post an answer your own question, since you said you solved it, or alternately delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `PERMISSION_DENIED` error was due to the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) set on Firestore. By default, the rules set on Firestore requires users to be authenticated for access. I suggest revisiting the rules set on your node to resolve this issue.