# Missing or insufficient permissions in firestore database android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firestore database. In that I have set security rules ture for all document read/write. But when i am using **get**, **update** and **delete** method from android it returns **Missing or insufficient permissions** error.

I have read in stackoverflow that collection should exists in database. I have tried that also but it didn't not work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47270946/7591349

Security Rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Get call from the android side:

```
App.instance?.firestoreDB?.collection(DBConstant.COLLECTION_USER)
         ?.whereEqualTo(USER_PHONE_NUMBER, numberCode)
         ?.get()
         ?.addOnSuccessListener {}
         ?.addOnFailureListener { e -> }
```

Response from firestore:

```
Listen for Query(user where phoneNumber == +918888888885) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

**Same code and same security rules** worked in my other firebase project but I could not figure it out what is wrong with this project.

==== EDITED ===

[image: Security Rules]

[image: Database Structure]