# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. -quasar & Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, permissions, quasar-framework, quasar

Im Using Quasar and Firebase

I Get FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. error on console

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSCLK.png)

Script:

```
    // gets from the firebase
const path = "/newpage";
    this.$auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
if (authUser) {
 
this.$bind('userz', this.$db.collection('users'));
 this.$db.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid).get()
              .then(snapshot => {
                const userData = snapshot.data();
                console.log(userData);

 (this.$route.path !== path);
  this.$router.push(path).catch(err => {});

 this.livePaper = false;


   })} else  {
    
 this.livePaper = true;
console.log('user logged out'); 
this.$router.push('/Login').catch(err => {});

}   
    })

  },
```

whenever I put

````
```this.$bind('userz', this.$db.collection('users'));```
````

missing permission happens

but when i remove the bind
It has no errors

though
I want to get the username: value in the field and put it on my nav

[firebase - username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH3xo.png)

````
``` <li v-for="(users, uid) in userz" :key="uid">
      {{users.username}} <q-btn v-on:click="livePaper = true"   label="Sign Out" @click="logOut()" color="green"/>
````

```

But i cant get it unless i remove

````
```this.$db.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid).get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            const userData = snapshot.data();
            console.log(userData);```
````

again when i remove it missing permission happens again.

what should I do

Whole Code:

````
<template>
  <q-layout view="hHh lpR fFf">

    <q-header elevated class="bg-primary text-white">
      <q-toolbar>
      
        <q-btn  v-if="!livePaper" dense flat round icon="menu" @click="left = !left" />

        <q-toolbar-title>
          <q-avatar>
            <img src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/logo/svg/quasar-logo.svg">
          </q-avatar>
          Title
        </q-toolbar-title>
 <div class="q-pa-md hid" v-if="!livePaper">
  
   <li v-for="(users, uid) in userz" :key="uid">
          {{users.username}} <q-btn v-on:click="livePaper = true"   label="Sign Out" @click="logOut()" color="green"/>
   </li>
  </div>
       
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>

       <q-drawer v-if="!livePaper" show-if-above v-model="left" side="left"  bordered>

      <!-- drawer content -->
       <q-scroll-area style="height: calc(100% - 150px); margin-top: 150px; border-right: 1px solid #ddd">
       <q-list padding>
            <q-item clickable v-ripple>
              <q-item-section avatar>
                <q-icon name="inbox" />
              </q-item-section>
 <q-item-section>
                Inbox
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item   clickable v-ripple>
              <q-item-section avatar>
                <q-icon name="star" />
              </q-item-section>

              <q-item-section>
                
                Star
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item clickable v-ripple>
              <q-item-section avatar>
                <q-icon name="send" />
              </q-item-section>

              <q-item-section>
                Send
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item clickable v-ripple>
              <q-item-section avatar>
                <q-icon name="drafts" />
              </q-item-section>

              <q-item-section>
                Drafts
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

             <q-item @click="icon = true" clickable v-ripple>
              <q-item-section avatar>
                 <q-dialog v-model="icon">
      <q-card style="width: 570px; max-width: 80vw;" class= "q-pa-xl ">
        <q-card-section class="row items-center q-pb-none ">
          <div class="text-h6">Sign Up</div>
          <q-space />
          <q-btn icon="close" flat round dense v-close-popup />
        </q-card-section>

         <q-separator />


   <q-card-section >
          <q-input filled v-model="usrnm" label="Username" id="usrnm" lazy-rules
       :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Please type something']"
      />

          <q-input filled v-model="eml" label="Email" id="eml" lazy-rules
       :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Please type something']"
      />

      <q-input
        filled
        type="password"
        v-model="pswrd"
        id="pswrd"
        label="Password"
        lazy-rules
         :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 ||'Please type a real age'
        ]"
      />

      <div>
        <q-btn label="Sign Up" type="submit" color="primary"  @click="signUps()" />
      
      </div>
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </q-dialog>
                <q-icon name="person_add" />
              </q-item-section>

              <q-item-section>
                Sign Up
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item> 

          </q-list>
        </q-scroll-area>
           
        <q-img class="absolute-top" src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/material.png" style="height: 150px">
          <div class="absolute-bottom bg-transparent">
            <q-avatar v-ripple size="56px" class="q-mb-sm">
              <img src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/boy-avatar.png">
            </q-avatar>
            <div class="text-weight-bold"></div>
            <div>@rstoenescu</div>
          </div>
        </q-img>
    </q-drawer>


    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>

  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      left: false,
      userz: [],
      livePaper: false,
        icon: false,
         eml: '',
      pswrd: '',
      usrnm: '',
      index: 0

    }
  },
  created() {

    // gets from the firebase
const path = "/newpage";
    this.$auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
if (authUser) {
 

 this.$db.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid)
              .get()
              .then(snapshot => {
                const userData = snapshot.data();
                console.log(userData);

 (this.$route.path !== path);
  this.$router.push(path).catch(err => {});
  this.$bind('userz', this.$db.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid));
    this.$bind('userz', this.$db.collection('users'));
 this.livePaper = false;


   })} else  {
    
 this.livePaper = true;
console.log('user logged out'); 
this.$router.push('/Login').catch(err => {});

}   
    })

  },
  methods: {

        logOut(){

   this.$auth.signOut();
 this.livePaper = true;
   },
 
                      
      signUps()  {
 this.$auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.eml, this.pswrd).then(cred => {
return this.$db.collection('users').doc(cred.userz.uid).set({
  email: this.eml,
  username: this.usrnm
});


      this.isEdit = false
      this.text = ''
      this.yr = ''
 }).then;(() => {


 });
  // ...
}
  }
}
</script> ```
````

Answer (score 5):

This might be a duplicate thread of
[firestore: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions?rq=1), at least this is where i got help for this problem.

After setting up the rules in a proper way, the error will disappear. I had the same problem with the quasar firebase sample app too.

Here are the docs for your the firebase rules that contain all the details for setting up the rules:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

basically the line

```
allow read, write: if false;
```

is the problem, you could change it to the following to allow only signed in users to access the database:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

the following code is not recommendable because it enables unauthenticated access to your database, so don't use it unless you are in a testing scenario:

```
allow read, write: if false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, you need to change the rouls from `false` to `true`:

[image]

To make it look like this:

[image]