# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions error even I have working auth rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know that firestore works behind rules, but even I changed rules to allow everything it doesn't work and it gives me this error(). The same rules work for my other project's firestore under the same account. Do you think is this a bug or am I skipping some point?

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firestore: PERMISSION\_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Can you share a image of the Firestore data you are trying to read and also include your code that tries to read it? Update the question please, there's not enough info for us to help.