# Firebase Firestore "Missing or insufficient permissions" despite open security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a document in Firebase Firestore. I have manually added documents to it in the Web UI, but am unable to do it programmatically.

The following is a single HTML file, containing all the code, which is directly taken from [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#add_data):

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "<REDACTED>",
        authDomain: "<REDACTED>",
        projectId: "<REDACTED>",
        storageBucket: "<REDACTED>",
        messagingSenderId: "<REDACTED>",
        appId: "<REDACTED>"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var db = firebase.firestore();

    // example from the docs
    db.collection("users").add({
        first: "Ada",
        last: "Lovelace",
        born: 1815
    })
        .then((docRef) => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
</script>
```

I have redacted the config object, but it was copied directly from the Firebase config page (furthermore, I know the config is correct because in another app (not pictured), Firebase Auth works just fine).

Upon opening the above HTML page, I get the following error in the console:

```
Error adding document:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

My Firestore security rules are as follows. They should be completely open to all reads and writes:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, update, delete, create: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Despite the "Missing or Insufficient Permissions" error, when I go to the "Monitor Rules" tab of the Firestore Rules page, I don't see any stats for the denied requests, as if the rules didn't even get evaluated at all, despite me having ran at least 50 requests over the last 24 hours:
[image: No denied requests]

Running simulated Firestore requests in the Firestore Rules Playground succeeds every time as expected, whether the request is "authenticated" or not.

Please advise, I am at a loss for what else to try.

Comment: did you enabled firestore ?

Comment: @Jithin I believe so. At least, I have manually added documents to it in the Web UI.

Comment: okay then you have initialized it, let me check again then

Comment: Can you try it again, the rules will take sometimes to implement, but when i tried on my end it works, i have given the same rule and the same code just like you given here with my credentials

Comment: I have just created a brand new project and ran the same code with the new project's config, and it worked... but it continues not to work with the config of the original project. Do you have any idea for what could be different between the two? I have made the new project into an almost exact copy of the original one (enabled the Auth service, created the same Firestore collections manually), and it continues to work on the new one.

Comment: I have nothing on my end, It's cause of the project now for sure, but if you have published the rules clearly then I don't know why. Even I tested your code on my old project, but one thing was that, the rules were like old ones, they were looking into timestamps and all, and i made to allow true for every thing,

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are looking at the rules of the right Firebase project? Look at the `projectId` in your code above and then make sure you select that one when you [check your rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/rules)

Comment: Yep, right one. Like I say, Firebase Auth works just fine on the same project.

Comment: What if you generate and use a new apiKey? Maybe the permissions for that are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sidestepped solving this issue by simply creating a new project. I still don't know what was wrong. Please see the comments below my question for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with Google support and found you need the
`firebaserules.system` IAM role. Here is what I received:

> Thank you for contacting Google Cloud Support. My name is Sakshi and I will be helping you with this issue.

> I understand that you are getting the error [1] on the existing Google project and want to debug this error without creating a new project.  Please correct me if I have misunderstood the issue.

> Please note that the service account or user account you are using to authenticate Firebase project need to have ‘firebaserules.system’ role, If you don’t have this role your security rules will deny all the incoming requests. I will suggest you refer to the document [2] to know more about this in detail.

> If your application is using the server client libraries or the REST or RPC APIs, please note that they bypass all Cloud Firestore security rules and instead authenticate through Google Application default credentials. Please follow this document [3] to know about Firebase security rules.

> I hope the provided information is useful. Please let me know if you have any questions regarding this issue.

> Regards,
> Sakshi
> Google Cloud Support

> [1] Firebase Firestore "Missing or insufficient permissions"
> [2] https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#security_rule_dependency_on_iam
> [3] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 1):

Following the @Mark Answer via the Google link (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#security_rule_dependency_on_iam)

Here's the quick command that solved the above issue(*Missing or insufficient permissions*).

Goto **google cloud** and **open** cloud **shell** in your browser type the following **command**:

> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_PROJECT_ID 
> --member=serviceAccount:service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@firebase-rules.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
> --role=roles/firebaserules.system

**Tip:**
For the **ProjectID** and **ProjectNumber** getting thing

If you're using the **Firebase CLI** for the above one and have already set up the project locally, then just type in the **terminal**

> firebase projects:list

Then you can simply see there's your Firebase project list along with the above details use the one you're experiencing issue.