# Flutter error - [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app that is generating the following error that is displayed above the app bar

```
 [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have
```

The error occurs when:

```
1). The current app user logs out of my app.
2). The login screen is presented  
3). The user logs in with a different user email/password
```

The error occurs AFTER the user has logged in.

No error logs appear in the IDE

I have the following Firestore rule set up

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents/{collection} {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the [minimal code that any of use can run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to trigger the error message against your rules/data?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore security rules are not wildcard-matched by default. Accordingly, if you specify a rule for a certain `document` or `collection`, it wont necessarily match `documents` or `subcollections` with the same level but different names. For any single `document` or `collection` you want to safeguard, rules must be explicitly defined.

You must specifically set rules for each level if you want security rules to be applied recursively to all `documents` in a `collection` or `subcollection`.

Here is an example of a Security Rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
collections
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /cities/{citiesID} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow update, delete: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }

    // By default, the fallback rule denies access.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

You may refer to this documentation about Writing Rules in [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules) and [Structuring Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure).

You may also check this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions) answers that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
The problem was a RiverPod StreamProvider that was calling a Firebase stream, and the RiverPod provider was missing the 'autodispose' suffix.

Without the 'autodispose' suffix the Firebase stream with the old user credentials was kept alive for the new user.