# Problem with checking if a userId is in an array with firestore rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore I have a project document which has an owner field an array with other users that can access that project. In Firestore rules I try to secure that with the following function

```
function isAuthorizedForProject(projectId) {
   let doc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Project/$(projectId)).data;
   let user = request.auth.uid;

   return doc.owner == user || (doc.users && doc.users[user] != null);
}
```

I use the function as follows:

```
match /Project/{projectId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                 (resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid || 
                 request.auth.uid in resource.data.users);

  allow update: if request.auth != null &&
    request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner &&
    request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['title']);

    match /Models/{modelId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && isAuthorizedForProject(projectId);
                
      match /Fields/{Field} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null && isAuthorizedForProject(projectId);
      }
   }
}
```

If I am logged in as the owner the function isAuthorizedForProject() works but if I am logged in as a user that is in the array users this function fails. Does anyone know what I do wrong?

This is the function I use to get the documents:

```
const projectCollectionRef = collection(db, "Project", `${document}`, "Models");
const modelsquery = await getDocs(projectCollectionRef);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to also show the **code** that accesses the database and doesn't work as expected, and the exact error message you get?

Comment: I added the two lines of code that give me the "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" error

Comment: can you check this `return doc.owner == user \|\| (doc.users && doc.users[user] != null)`  is this  checking if `user` is equal to `doc.users[user]`or not?Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: doc.users is an array with users that are allowed to access the project. so doc.users[user] != null should check if the user is in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the function to:

```
    function isAuthorizedForProject(projectId) {
       let doc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Project/$(projectId)).data;
       let user = request.auth.uid;
    
       return doc.owner == user || (user in doc.users);
    }
```

Which solved the issue. Turns out that this code (in my previous function):

```
(doc.users && doc.users[user] != null)
```

returned an array and not a Bool.