Why is the Streambuilder not updating the UI?
I am uploading an image, then storing it in Firebase Storage, and then store the link in the Firebase database. I have added a Streambuilder to update the UI. However, I am getting a never ending circular progress bar when I do that. I am sure there is something wrong with my Streambuilder code.

Code snippet as follows:
class EditProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfile({
    super.key,
    required this.userData,
  });
  final UserModel userData;

  @override
  State<EditProfile> createState() => _EditProfileState();
}

class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {
.....

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 75,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                widget.userData.profileImage.toString()),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      }),

Please let me know where should I make the code changes.


You should also check for hasError to see if there was an exception. currently that would show the spinner too.

yes, it apparently has some error. How to find what the error is?

hasn't the snapShot an error property?

What do you mean?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html

It has a non null error, but how to find it?

and what is the content of that error property?

Using Try catch ?

just set a breakpoint in your if and inspect that object

I have updated the error image in the question. Please check.

The problem is probably due to how the StreamBuilder is handling different states of the snapshot.
The CircularProgressIndicator appears running constantly because there is no proper handling for the connection state, errors, and empty data cases.
specifically, the problem might be in your code, you are doing:
 if (snapshot.hasData) { // ---> Only if there's data
      return CircleAvatar(
        radius: 75,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.userData.profileImage.toString()),
      );
    } else {
       // --> if there's no data or loading
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

which means, only if there are actual documents (e.g, .hasData) will it show the CircleAvatar.
Instead, you can use, which will account for all correct loading states and if there's data (documents):
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      print(snapshot.error); // --> Debug the error here
      return const Text('Something went wrong');
    } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
      return const Text('No data available');
    } else {
      return CircleAvatar(
        radius: 75,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.userData.profileImage.toString()),
      );
    }
  },
),

Note:
If there's an error (which might be your case), it will show the text "Something went wrong" - which you'll have to debug (I added print(snapshot.error) ).

I am getting the snapshot.hasError state always (Something went wrong). So yes have to debug and figure out what went wrong. Not sure whats the best approach.

@M99Coder You can print(snapshot.error).  I edited my answer  with that code.

[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions. This is the issue.

@M99Coder Ah, cause your db is locked with different permissions. Please close this question and consider reading the documentation on Firestore rules.

@M99Coder see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46590155/12349734

So the errors are all gone, the firebase profileImage in Users is getting updated but the UI is not getting udpated. Why would that happen?

@M99Coder not sure, with the current approach everything should be working . I’d suggest you open a new question
